# Spherical completeness in general complete metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

As is commonly known, in a complete metric space, for a family of closed ball covers $B(x_{n}, r_{n})$, if the radius $\{r_{n}\}$ tends toward zero, there exists a unique point that lies within the intersection of these closed ball covers. However, with regard to this proposition, I seek to explore how altering the condition of the radius $\{r_{n}\}$ not tending towards zero would yield different outcomes. In fact, it can be demonstrated that for any collection of compact sets in a given metric space, if the intersection of any finite subset of them is non-empty, then the intersection of these compact sets is also non-empty. Consequently, the intersection of closed ball covers in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is always non-empty. Nevertheless, in more general complete metric spaces, closed balls may not necessarily be compact.

In such cases, my problem is: how to construct examples where the intersection of closed ball covers with radius $\{r_{n}\}$ is not tending towards zero and results in an empty set.

Comment: I don't think your result is commonly known, or even correct for that matter.  Can you provide a reference where this result is stated?

Comment: @Aweygan I'm pretty sure the OP is referring to Cantor's Intersection Theorem, and forgot to mention the sets must be nested descendingly. Is this correct, Jonny? Are you assuming the sets are nested here?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my expression is not clearly enough,the sets are nested here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Let $X = \Bbb{N} = \{1, 2, \ldots\}$. Define a metric on $X$:
$$d(a, b) = \cases{1 + 2^{-\min\{a,b\}} & if $a 
\neq b$ \\ 0 & if $a = b$.}$$
This is clearly symmetric and positive-definite. Triangle inequality,
$$d(a, c) \le d(a, b) + d(b, c)$$
holds because, unless $a = b$ or $b = c$ (in which case it's trivial), the right hand side is always at least $2$, while the left hand side is at most $3/2$.

Further, since $d(a, b) \ge 1$ for all $a \neq b$, the space is discrete, and the only Cauchy sequences are eventually constant, and hence convergent. This implies $X$ is complete. We now just need to construct the family of nested balls.

Let $x_n = n$ and $r_n = 1 + 2^{-n}$. Then $B(x_n; r_n) = \{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}$. Then we have
$$B(x_{n+1}; r_{n+1}) \subseteq B(x_n; r_n)$$
and
$$\bigcap_n B(x_n; r_n) = \emptyset$$
as required. Of course, $r_n \not\to 0$, but this follows from the Cantor Intersection Theorem.